# Cómo evitar repetir código HTML en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con **PHP 7.3** y me encuentro con el problema de que tengo que hacer un menú desplegable dinámico. No sé cómo hacer para no repetir el código HTML y que el menú se genere dependiendo de un contador.

Adjunto el código que quiero simplificar:

```
<nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Menú usuario</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="ejercicios4Coach.php" >Pack inicial</a> 
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"                              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropright">
                        <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright"                             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropright">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"                              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropright">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"                              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropright">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Como podéis ver repito el mismo código HTML una y otra vez. No sé si hay alguna forma de hacer una función o un bucle que me lo genere.

Este código es un **dropdown de bootstrap 4**.

Comment: Esos **Action** ¿son fijos o dependen de una base de datos o de otra información?

Comment: Lo ideal seria cambiar solo el número por el contador, pero si supone un problema podria dejarlos fijos, aunque lo ideal seria que se incrementara según fuese añadiendo.

Comment: El **Action1** es diferente porque cambia la clase. ¿Cambia por algún motivo? ¿Sólo ocurre con el primer elemento o podría pasar con más?

Comment: No, todos serán iguales, es una prueba que hice y me olvide de quitar.

Comment: Perfecto. Te pongo el ejemplo con ambas soluciones (iterando cadenas y números).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solución iterando los textos a mostrar

La parte que se repite podrías generarla así:

```
<?php foreach (['Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3', 'Action4', 'Action5'] as $valor): ?>
<li class="nav-item dropright">
    <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?= $valor ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

### Solución mediante un bucle contador

También podrías hacerlo mediante un bucle contador de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php for ($num = 1; $num <= 5; $num++): ?>
<li class="nav-item dropright">
    <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action<?= $num ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Me funciona genial, muchas gracias, habria alguna forma de que los action dentro del foreach tambien se incrementaran por un counter?

Comment: Todo es posible. ¿Prefieres con contador? Y lo de la clase.. ¿tiene que ser el primero `dropdown` en vez de `dropright` por algún motivo?

Comment: No, solo estaba probando y no lo cambié, en principio serán todos dropdown, me gustaría que fuese con contador porque así se hace todo automático, el contador es una variable INT almacenada en la base de datos, si es un 7 pues generar 7

Comment: Listo, espero que sea lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Genial, solo tengo que cambiar el 5 del for por el contador y me funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias <3

Comment: Se me ha presentado otra duda pero esto ya es por curiosidad, probando a hacer un bucle dentro de otro para poder hacer también que lo que se muestra en el desplegable dependa de una variable, me ha da problemas, como se haría?

Comment: No sé exactamente a qué te refieres. ¿Podrías abrir una nueva pregunta explicando un poco mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer y qué te está fallando?

Comment: ya publique la pregunta, seguramente la solución es muy simple pero me gustaria saber todas las posibilidad que se pueden llegar a hacer, incluyendo recursividad y todo eso. gracias.